# Google glass : Location recognition in Google glass

Tags: google-glass

How Google glass recognizes location when the user captures an image in Google glass,

1. Using GPS Tag or
2. Image Recognition

please give brief description.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to be the Geotagging GPS tag, for, Google glass has only a 2D camera and has only a OMAP 4430 SoC, dual-core cpu which does not gives enough information and cpu power for the glass to do Image Recognition.

So far, only devices has fancy cameras, like the one in project tango, has Image Recognition

Even Google Glass itself does not have a GPS chip, it would pull location information from cell phone.